# What is the maximum distance that Patriot missile launchers can communicate over?

Tags: command-and-conquer-generals

The Patriot Missile Launcher system is the USA base defence structure in Command and Conquer: Generals. Their tooltip says;

> Detect enemy stealth units, **can relay enemy position to nearby Patriots**

This means that if you build multiple Patriot Missile Launchers in close vicinity to each other, they will relay the position of enemies allowing launchers that may be out of range of attack to still fire at an incoming enemy once it has been detected by another Patriot Missile Launcher.

How close do I have to place the Patriot Missile Launchers to each other in order to qualify as 'nearby'?

Comment: relativly close, as i remember. but as this isnt specific, i wont post it.

Comment: O wait, I do somewhat remember this! It's *about* the length of 3.5 Paladine tanks parked back to back. (longways, not width ways) Or about the size of 2 supply drop stations put next to each other.

Comment: Maybe if the bounty was more, I would perhaps install generals just to test this ... :P though, this is making me want to play generals now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Weapon.ini config file tells us that `RequestAssistRange = 200`. For comparison, the anti-aircraft firing range of a Patriot battery is 700.